# SVN changes without merge conflicts

Tags: svn, merge

Suppose I have an SVN repository with two branches, and a certain file exists in both branches and differs by one line. Is there a way to allow users to modify that line on either branch and merge to the other without SVN flagging a merge conflict? In other words, is there a way to tell SVN to treat those different lines as though they were the same?

As an example, suppose I have a branch named "B", which has a file `foo.txt` whose contents are as follows:

```
1
2
apple
4
```

From this branch I create a branch named "C":

`svn   cp   ^/branches/B   ^/branches/C`

Then I modify `branches/C/foo.txt` to the following (and then commit):

```
1
2
banana
4
```

Is there anything I can do (other than modify the contents of the files) that will allow a user to modify `foo.txt` on either branch and merge to the other without SVN flagging a merge conflict?

I will also specify:

- The purpose is to be able to merge in both directions. It is not enough to be able to merge from B to C only, or from C to B only.
- I have already tried to record-only merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subversion will report a conflict because there *is* a conflict. Subversion's workflow is pretty rigid about how merging works:

- merge into your working copy
- resolve conflicts in your working copy
- commit the merge with all conflicts resolved

You can, however, use Subversion's automatic conflict resolution to specify which version to accept. To merge from *C* to *B* you could do this:

```
# we are on B
svn merge --accept theirs-conflict ^/branches/C .
```

This will use the contents from *B* for all conflicts. To limit to one specific file (and resolve all other conflicts manually), you could do:

```
# we are on B
svn merge --accept postpone ^/branches/C . 
svn resolve --accept theirs-conflict foo.txt
```

Or use a cherry-pick merge:

```
# we are on B and know only foo.txt was changed in r123
svn merge -c 123 --accept theirs-conflict ^/branches/C .
```

Also see the documentation on `--accept` in [Advanced Merging](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html) and the possible values can be found [here](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.resolve).